# Get string with base-16 (hex) rendering of the bytes of an ASCII string

Tags: go

E.g.

```
input := "Office"
want := "4f6666696365" // Note: this is a string!!
```

I know that string literals are stored in UTF-8 already. 
What is the easiest way to get convert this to string in UTF-8 representation?

Calling `EncodeRune` on each character seems too cumbersome.

Comment: As you know, ["string literals are UTF-8"](https://blog.golang.org/strings). So, why are referring to ASCII?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're looking for is a string that contains the hex representation of your input string.  That is not UTF-8. (Any string that's valid ASCII is also valid UTF-8.)

In any case, this is how to do what you want:

```
want := fmt.Sprintf("%x", []byte(input))
```